# Stacks Clarity language Post-Conditions

Tags: stack, blockchain, smartcontracts, clarity-lang, stacks-blockchain

my question is about post-conditions, I dont really understand them.

I tried minting NFT's from the sandbox and it has not worked because of post conditions.

I also tried minting my own nft on testnet and one contract worked and the other didn't.  How can you tell if there are post conditions?

Also, I found the Syvita sandbox that apparently allows for post-conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Post conditions are used to verify that certain conditions are met when a function is called. They are not part of the smart contract, but instead are defined on the front end and are an additional layer of security the developer can add to make sure the expected actions are the only things that happen.

Here's an example of how you can add a post condition making sure that greater than or equal to a certain amount of STX was transferred.

```js
import {
  FungibleConditionCode,
  makeStandardSTXPostCondition,
  makeContractSTXPostCondition,
} from '@stacks/transactions';

// With a standard principal
const postConditionAddress = 'SP2ZD731ANQZT6J4K3F5N8A40ZXWXC1XFXHVVQFKE';
const postConditionCode = FungibleConditionCode.GreaterEqual;
const postConditionAmount = 12345n;

const standardSTXPostCondition = makeStandardSTXPostCondition(
  postConditionAddress,
  postConditionCode,
  postConditionAmount
);
```

You can read more about post conditions in this tutorial: https://dev.to/stacks/understanding-stacks-post-conditions-e65